# Import Multibit multibit.key into Electrum

Tags: electrum, multibit, private-key-import

Have a multibit.key file from an old Multibit Wallet, but can't import it into Electrum.

When I copy and paste the char string from the file into the "Import Addresses and Private Keys" Electrum window it just never allows me to push Next and proceed.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem, and the only solution I found was to send all my bitcoin to another address (remember to put the fee to the maximum amount) because it was also impossible to import this key on the the new Multibit HD wallet...

You're not doing anything wrong except trusting multibit back in the days to store your bitcoin...

Comment: Thanks. Multibit was great in its heyday. Multibit HD is discontinued now as well I think - be careful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with one of my customers and found out that Multibit had generated an invalid key due to a bug in the software. This key cannot be used because it is out-of-range of the bitcoin EC specs. Check if your key is working with any other software. We are currently working on a solution - you can PM me.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to solve this issue - my attempted transfer from Multibit to a modern wallet went through once the fees got lower (it took about a month!).